# Prove that there exist a regular covering of the 8 figure of degree at most $n!$

Tags: covering-spaces

> Let $\phi : Y \rightarrow X$ be a $n$-sheet covering of the 8 figure. Prove that there exist $\psi : Z \rightarrow X$ an at most $n!$- sheet regular covering such that the diagram commutes (where $\mu$ is a covering).
> $\require{AMScd}$
> \begin{CD}
> Z @>\mu>> Y\\
> @V \psi V V @VV \phi V\\
> X @>>Id> X
> \end{CD}

(Sorry, but I don't know how to draw diagonal arrows with this code. It should have an arrow $\psi$ from $Z$ to $X$)

I have been thinking of doing this by induction. Assuming the statement true for $(n-1)$-sheeted coverings. We enumerate the $n$ vertices of $Y$.

I want to apply the statement to $Y_1',\ldots, Y_n'$, where $Y_j'$ is $Y$ without the vertex $j$. Here I glue the corresponding arrows arriving and leaving (from the viewpoint of the vertex $j$, $a^{-1}$ continues as $a$ and the same with $b$, where $a$ and $b$ are the arrows that project to each loop in figure 8. If there is any loop in $j$, I simply ignore it).

Each time I will obtain an at most (n-1)!-sheeted regular covering $Z_j$ satisfying the conditions. But I don't see how to glue them to obtain the at most $n\times (n-1)!$-sheeted regular covering.

This idea comes to me just by the numbers involved.
Maybe I should proceed in a different way. Any advice? Thanks

Comment: Using the correspondence between (path-connected) covering projections over (sufficiently nice) spaces $X$ and conjugacy classes of subgroups of $ \pi_1(X)$, what you are trying to show reduces to proving that if $H$ is a subgroup of finite index $n$ of a group $G$ , then $H$ contains a normal subgroup of index at most $n!$. This can be proved by considering the kernel of the homomorphism $G \to S_n$ you get from the left (or right) action of $G$ on the cosets of $H$.

Comment: @RobArthan Thank you, sir. Your comment has been extremely useful.